# cut object's value to the last JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I cut the 6th object's value and paste it into the last object? Below is the result of this code :

```
JSON.parse(json).forEach(function(obj, idx, array) {  
                  console.log(obj);
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by cut and paste in this context, are you looking to filter all objects that have type award?

Comment: is it based on index.. or a value in the object

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Updated: As you mentioned that if any object has an value must be cut
>   and moved to the last,

```
  var array = JSON.parse(json),
      index;


   array.forEach(function(obj, idx) {  
       if(obj.itemId) {
           index = idx;
       }
    });     

   if(typeof index !=="undefined") {
      var tempObj = array.splice(index,1);
        // adding it the end
      array.push(tempObj);
   }
```

It will remove the last element with itemId and move it to the end.

Comment: the 6th item sometime would be at place 2, 3 and etc, and it may appear multiple times.. I want to grad the latest item and put in into the last.

Comment: Updated the answer. Now it's based on itemId. In case you want it to be based on placeholder, just replace itemId with placeholdId

Comment: u still hard coded something which is wrong. says the object has itemId : 1,2,3, I want the 3th to be moved onto the last.

Comment: I've updated the answer now. You mean that if any element has itemId filled, then move it to the last?

Comment: yes but only the last itemid will move to the last.

Comment: Only the last itemId? say i have 9 objects and in this only 6th object is having an itemId. then i need to cut that and move it to the last index of array?

Comment: Will clean that up. So you want with sorting or without that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74539/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-james-lemon).

Comment: what if it has 3 itemId? will it get the 3th and the earlier 2 remain the same?

Comment: Yes, remaining two will remain the same :)

Comment: what the push is not within the loop?

Answer (score 0):

James,

I have some few question just to get my understanding clear before providing an answer.

1. So, you want to remove the 6th item in array and want to replace that with the last item ?
2. The item you are going to remove is always going to be 6th item ?

***Answer:***

```
var item, items = JSON.parse(json), itemCount = items.length, obj, position;
for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    if (item.itemId) {
        position = i;
    }
}

if (position) {
    items.push(items.splice(position, 1));
}
```

The code above will make sure that if the item appears at last position will also be handled. If you want to clone the object instead of referencing the old one then you need to loop through the object and update the new one like below

```
if (position) {
    obj = items.splice(position, 1);
    item = {};
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            item[property] = obj[property];
        }
    }
    items.push(item);
}
```

Comment: 1. place the 6th's value into the last. 2. No, it may appear multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to replace the last object with the object with type:"award".
Then I would do it like this:

```
JSON.parse(json).forEach(function(obj, idx, array) {  
    if (obj.type === "award") {
      array[array.length - 1] = obj;
    }
});
```

if the award is already the last, it will only be overwritten by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.prototype.splice() to remove the element you want.  Push it to the end.

```
var arr = [];
var tgtIdx = -1;
var lastID = -1;

JSON.parse(json).forEach(function (obj, idx, array) {
    if(obj.itemId !== null && obj.itemId > lastID) {
        tgtIdx = idx;
        lastID = obj.itemId;
    }

    arr.push(obj);
})

if(tgtIdx >= 0 && tgtIdx < arr.length - 1) {
    arr.push(arr.splice(tgtIdx, 1)[0]);
}
```

Comment: nope, I want to search for the last itemId that has value, not 5.

Comment: Looks like the splice answer was incorporated into some of these answers, but I cleaned up my answer now that what you're asking for is more clear.  If I understand correctly, you want the object with the highest ID moved to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your get an array of objects, iterate through all the objects and you will end up with the last object that has award in its type key.

```
for(var i = 0, _len = obj.length; i < _len; i += 1) {
    if(obj[i].type === "award") {
        ourObj = obj[i];
    }
}

obj[obj.length-1] = ourObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter it:

```
var res = JSON.parse(json).filter(function(value) {
    return value.itemId == 6;
});
```